# Montgomery algorithms for Lattice based schemes

Tags: algorithm-design, lattice-crypto, montgomery-multiplication

Why most of Lattice based scheme use Montgomery Multiplication algorithm?

Comment: Just my 2 cents: Any cryptosystem that uses groups and some kind of multiplication operation probably uses Montgomery. I'd consider Montgomery an implementation detail though.

Comment: I wonder if there is any other reason than efficiency

Comment: Known ways of protection against side channel attacks maybe.